# Comparación de fecha con IF

Tags: php, echo

quisiera apoyo al comparar una fecha

Quiero que tome en cuenta $fecha y que entre la fecha y por ejemplo un año me marque garantía activa. No me doy una idea y casi no veo algo similar.

Se los agradecería si me pueden apoyar a completar mi código

```
$fecha ='2023-01-01 10:21:00';
if($fecha ){
echo"Garantia activa";
}else{
echo"Garantia inactiva";}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si estas usando formato `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`, [como debe ser](https://www.google.com/search?q=iso+8601+notation), puedes comparar las cadenas de fecha directamente sin hacer cálculos.

```php
$fecha = '2023-01-01 10:21:00';
$current_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // fecha actual

if($current_date < $fecha) {
    echo "Garantia activa";
} else {
    echo "Garantia inactiva";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Para comparar una fecha con la fecha actual y verificar si ha pasado un año, puedes usar la función `strtotime` para convertir la fecha a un formato de tiempo que PHP pueda manejar, y luego restarle un año en segundos.

```
$fecha = '2023-01-01 10:21:00';

// Convertir la fecha a un formato de tiempo
$timestamp = strtotime($fecha);

// Restar un año (31536000 segundos)
$garantia_timestamp = $timestamp + 31536000;

if(time() < $garantia_timestamp){
    echo "Garantia activa";
} else {
    echo "Garantia inactiva";
}
```

`time()` devuelve el tiempo actual en segundos y luego comparamos con `strtotime` ese valor con la fecha límite de garantía y sumando un año en segundos. *Si la fecha actual es anterior a la fecha límite, entonces la garantía está activa.*

Answer (score 2):

Te recomendaría que uses la clase [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php) y sus derivados para trabajar con fechas y horas.

Esta clase ofrece una gran flexibilidad para hacer simples cálculos que de otro modo podrían ser complicados.

Veamos un ejemplo donde usaremos además el método [`diff()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.diff.php), en caso de que interese mostrar cuántos días faltan para que la garantía expire o la cantidad de días pasados desde que expiró. Esto es útil por ejemplo si se quiere enviar notificaciones automáticas `N` días antes de la expiración, ofrecer un plan más interesante a aquellos que no renovaron o cosas por el estilo.

Vamos a encapsular el código en una función, por si quieres reutilizar código y la probaremos con dos casos de uso.

```
#Garantía vigente
checkWarranty("2023-05-05 10:21:00");
echo PHP_EOL;
#Garantía expirada
checkWarranty("2023-03-05 10:21:00");

function checkWarranty($expiryDateString) {
    $currentDate = new DateTime();                   //Fecha actual
    $expiryDate = new DateTime($expiryDateString);  //Fecha de expiración
    $diff = $currentDate->diff($expiryDate);        //Diferencia entre las fechas
    $msg = ($currentDate > $expiryDate) ? "La garantía expiró hace %d días" : "Garantía vigente por %d días";
    printf($msg,$diff->days);    
}
```

**Salida:**

```
Garantía vigente por 15 días
La garantía expiró hace 45 días
```

Cabe decir que es una función muy básica. Convendría controlar nulos, y retornar quizá sólo un valor y acoplar la lógica donde recibes la respuesta de la función.